# HTML not displaying data from API but displays in console in .ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I successfully fetched data from my API and I can see it in console log. Here is a copy of that data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "10950",
        "name": "Name One",
        "adress": "Some street 3",
        "location": "City 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "10951",
        "name": "Name Two",
        "adress": "Some street 2",
        "location": "City 3"
    }

]
```

But hear this out:
When I want to show this data in HTML at first it doesn't show it. Then I click to another page in the same  app (another route) and go back to this route and everything shows in HTML. I was confused so I made a button which has (click)="onInit()" and when I click it it shows everything. But of course this is not good, I want to display data immediately.

Don't know if this could help, but I found out that it displays data in html even when I just open DevTools. And when I close, HTML data stays displayed. In other words, everything is displayed except when I want it to be - right when the page is loading.

Here are some snippets that I think could help:

```
//this is a class that gets data in loadData()
export class PocetnaStranicaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    router: Router;
    sub!: Subscription;
    poslovnice: PoslovnicaModel[] = [];

    constructor(private productService: APIService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    loadData(){
        this.sub = this.productService.getPoslovniceListSve().subscribe(response=>{
            this.poslovnice = response;
            console.log(this.poslovnice);
        });
    }
}
```

and this is html part that causes problems:

```
<div>
    <h1 class="poslovnica-title">POSLOVNICE</h1>
    <!--<button (click)="ngOnInit()">Prikaži</button>-->
</div>
<div class="poslovnica-box" *ngFor="let poslovnica of poslovnice" routerLink="poslovnica/{{poslovnica.id}}">
    <p class="poslovnica-text">POSLOVNICA</p>
    <h1 class="poslovnica-ime-text">{{poslovnica.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

in api service:

```
getPoslovniceListSve(): Observable<PoslovnicaModel[]> {

        let myUrl: string = API_URL + '/poslovnica/list';
    
        return this.http.get<PoslovnicaModel[]>(myUrl, this.httpUtils.getHTTPHeader());
    }
```

I tried millions of answers - from async pipe to '?' operators, *ngIf="poslovnice" etc. but it gave no result. I am confused why this happens, and thankful for every help you provide.

Comment: May we see the service method for `getPoslovniceListSve()`?

Comment: Do you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your `@Component` decorator?

Comment: @Totati yes I do have it

Comment: With OnPush strategy, angular will not listen to the changes of your `poslovnice`. 2 solutions : 1 -- Change to default. 2 - - Don't subscribe to the observable in your `.ts` but rather with ` | async` in your template

Comment: In general I recommend not switching to `OnPush` unless you really have performance issues.

Comment: you're right. that line was from some tutorial I found, and totally forgot about it when I changed my code. thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am curious to figure out the source of this issue (possible a change detection strategy setting), I would like to recommend the following strategy. You said that you tried to use the `async` pipe, but I wanted to provide a full example. Plus, it shows how much boilerplate you can reduce.

Component TS

```
export class PocetnaStranicaComponent {
  poslovnice$: Observable<PoslovnicaModel[]>;

  constructor(
    private productService: APIService,
    // Not sure why you need these next two items, but I added them anyway
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.poslovnice$ = this.productService.getPoslovniceListSve();
  }
}
```

Component HTML

```
<div>
    <h1 class="poslovnica-title">POSLOVNICE</h1>
</div>
<div class="poslovnica-box" *ngFor="let poslovnica of poslovnice$ | async" routerLink="poslovnica/{{poslovnica.id}}">
    <p class="poslovnica-text">POSLOVNICA</p>
    <h1 class="poslovnica-ime-text">{{poslovnica.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, thank you so much!! :) I hope someone will figure out what was the problem in my approach, I'm very curious.

Answer (score 0):

I aggree with @Joshua McCarthy, I prefer his solution. But for you, when you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component decorator, angular will update your template only when an `@Input()` changes, or `@Output()` event raises. When you have a http call, you have detect changes manually with calling [markForCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#markforcheck) in your `subscribe`.

```js
//this is a class that gets data in loadData()
export class PocetnaStranicaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    router: Router;
    sub!: Subscription;
    poslovnice: PoslovnicaModel[] = [];

    constructor(
        private productService: APIService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    loadData(){
        this.sub = this.productService.getPoslovniceListSve().subscribe(response=>{
            this.poslovnice = response;
            this.cdRef.markForCheck();
        });
    }
}
```